# How to re order a typescript object/StringMap to have the last element first

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary, tsx

I'm working in a .tsx file and am completely new to TS/React. I am trying to add a key/value pair to a StringMap at the very first index.

I have some code below that:

takes in the StringMap 'stats',

goes through each row and extracts clan from a string,

adds each clan to 'clans' (string[]),

creates a new stats map with clans 'statsWithClans'

```
function handlePlayerStatssWindow(stats: StringMap<string>) 
{
const rawFields = Object.keys(stats).map((key, i) => (
    <div key={i}>
        {key}: {stats[key]}
    </div>
));

var clans: string[] = [];

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(stats)) 
{
    const roles: string[] = value.split(',');
    for(const role of roles)
    {
        if(role.includes('clan='))
        {
            clans.push(role.replace('clan=',''));
        }
    }
}

const statsWithClans = {...stats};
statsWithClans.clans = clans.toString();

// const statsWithClans = {clans: (clans.toString()), ...stats};

const formattedFields = Object.keys(statsWithClans).map((key, i) => (
    <div key={i}>
        {key}: {statsWithClans[key]}
    </div>
));
}
```

The code works and outputs something like:

```
Name: Jeff
Class: Mage
Clans: Clan1, Clan2
```

If I try creating the map with clans at the start like so

> const statsWithClans = {clans: (clans.toString()), ...stats};

Typescript complains saying:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ groups: string; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ groups: string; }'.ts(7053)

and 'statsWithClans[key]' is highlighted

StringMap defintion

```
export default interface StringMap<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}
```

Comment: What's a `StringMap`?  Is this code a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue in a standalone IDE?

Comment: added StringMap definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#27273](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27273).  If you do [spread an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) into an object literal with other properties, the compiler silently drops the index signature.  Since your `StringMap<T>` type has an index signature, that is what's happening:

```
const oops = { clans: (clans.toString()), ...stats };
// const oops: {  clans: string; }
```

The index signature on `stats` is forgotten, and the new variable has type `{clans: string}`, with no index signature.  And you can't index into a value with an arbitrary `string` key unless that value has a string index signature.

The easiest way to deal with this in your example code is to explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of your `stats` variable:

```
const statsWithClans: StringMap<string> =
  { clans: (clans.toString()), ...stats }; // okay
```

Now `statsWithClans` is of the expected type and the rest of your code behaves as desired:

```
const formattedFields = Object.keys(statsWithClans).map((key, i) => (
  <div key={i}>
    {key}: {statsWithClans[key]} // okay
  </div>
));
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4#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-HUonk71fKn05mIG0PJQC9n+YMYHQ5MVSuVgfUmq1RkTRwF2bWDf1BmBhqMJlMqrNdosVmtOhsto8ZWIDkdKwe62H4e4LhOc9O7g3ncKzPs8BhAA)

Comment: thanks for taking the time to draft this writeup, great explanation!